# Erro ao fazer upload de arquivo no formulário django, Form nunca é valido

Tags: python-3.x, django, formulário

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um organizador de projetos, após eu renderizar o meus campos do form quando faço o upload do arquivo no meu formulario, o request.FILES me mostra os dados do arquivo que fiz upload, porem o form.cleaned_data['campo'] mostra o campo vazio ou da erro na chave.
ja tentei alterar meu formulario, retirei a função de limpar os campos do arquivos, alterei o models e nada de mudar o resultado.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver
from django.urls import reverse
import uuid

# Create your models here.
def get_local_for_upload_projetos(instances, filename):
    return f'projetos/{instances.setor}/{instances.nome}/{instances.projetista.first_name}/{filename}'

    class Projeto(models.Model):
    
    setores = (
        ('DAC', 'Dutos e Acessórios'),
        ('PRD', 'Produção'),
        ('ABG', 'Abrigo Subterrânio'),
        ('CMM', 'Container Modular Montável'),
        ('CPT', 'Celposte'),
        ('DCP', 'Departamento de Corte Plasma'),
        ('MCR', 'Missão Critica'),
        ('MDC', 'Mini Data Center'),
        ('MPE', 'Montagem Paineis Eletricos'),
        ('PRI', 'Preparação de Insumos'),
        ('RPE', 'Refrigeração e Projetos Especiais'),
        ('SEA', 'Sistemas Eletricos e Automação'),
        ('OUT', 'Outros'),
        )
    
    status = (
        ('DISP', 'Disponivel'),
        ('DOWN', 'Em Uso')
        )

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='ID unico para esse projeto em particular')
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Insira o nome para o projeto')
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=500, help_text='Descreva o projeto com no maximo 500 characteres')
    setor = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=setores, default='PRD', help_text='Defina Para Qual Setor o Projeto Foi Feito')
    data = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    projetista = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=status, default='Disponivel', help_text='Status do Projeto')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['setor']
        verbose_name = 'Projeto'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Projetos'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.nome}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Retorna o URL para acessar uma instância específica do modelo."""
        return reverse('projeto-detalhe', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if not self.id:
           self.slug = slugify(self.nome)



class ArquivoProjeto(models.Model):
    projeto = models.ForeignKey('Projeto', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    arquivo_projeto = models.FileField(upload_to=get_local_for_upload_projetos)
    arquivo_desenho = models.FileField(upload_to=get_local_for_upload_projetos, blank=True, null=True)
    arquivo_estrutura_de_projeto = models.FileField(upload_to=get_local_for_upload_projetos)
    arquivo_estrutura_de_fixadores = models.FileField(upload_to=get_local_for_upload_projetos, blank=True, null=True)
    arquivo_3D = models.FileField(upload_to=get_local_for_upload_projetos, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['projeto']
        verbose_name = 'Arquivo Projeto'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Arquivos Projetos'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.nome}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Retorna o URL para acessar uma instância específica do modelo."""
        return reverse('projeto-detalhe', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Projeto)
def arquivo_projeto_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Pass false so FileField doesn't save the model.
    instance.arquivo_projeto.delete(False)
    instance.arquivo_estrutura_de_projeto.delete(False)
    instance.arquivo_estrutura_de_fixadores.delete(False)
    instance.arquivo_3D.delete(False)
```

**forms.py**

```
import datetime
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.text import slugify
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from GerenciadorProjetos.models import Projeto
from crispy_forms.layout import HTML, Layout, Submit

class CadastroProjetoForm(forms.Form):

    id = forms.UUIDField()
    nome =  forms.CharField(label='Nome', max_length=100)
    descricao = forms.CharField(label='Descrição', max_length=500)
    setor = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Projeto.setores)
    data = forms.DateField()
    projetista = forms.CharField(label='Projetista Responsável', max_length=100)
    slug = forms.SlugField()
    projeto = forms.FileField()
    desenho = forms.FileField(required=False)
    estruturaprojeto = forms.FileField()
    estruturafixadores = forms.FileField(required=False)
    arquivo3D = forms.FileField(required=False)

    def clean_descricao(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['descricao']

        if len(data) > 500:
            raise ValidationError(_('Limite maximo de characteres atingido por favor use no maximo 500 characteres'))

        return data
                
    def clean_data(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['data']

        if data > datetime.date.today():
            raise ValidationError(_('Data invalida, O projeto não pode ter uma data de registro no futuro'))

        return data 

    def cleaned_slug(self):

        data = self.cleaned_data['nome']
        data = slugify(data)

        return data
```

**views.py**

```
def CadastrarProjeto(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CadastroProjetoForm(request.POST)
        arquivo_projeto = request.FILES.get('arquivo_projeto')
        arquivo_estrutura_de_projeto = request.FILES.get('arquivo_estrutura_de_projeto')
        
        if request.FILES.get('arquivo_desenho'):
            arquivo_desenho = request.FILES.get('arquivo_desenho')
        else:
            arquivo_desenho = None

        if request.FILES.get('arquivo_estrutura_de_fixadores'):
            arquivo_estrutura_de_fixadores = request.FILES.get('arquivo_estrutura_de_fixadores')
        
        if request.FILES.get('arquivo_3D'):
            arquivo_desenho = request.FILES.get('arquivo_3D')

        #import ipdb
        #ipdb.set_trace()

        if form.is_valid():
            projeto = form.save()
            ArquivoProjeto.objects.create(projeto=projeto, arquivo_projeto=arquivo_projeto)

            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index') )

    # If this is a GET (or any other method) create the default form.
    else:
        data = datetime.date.today()
        uid = uuid.uuid4
        form = CadastroProjetoForm(initial={'data': data, 'id': uid})

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'GerenciadorProjetos/projeto_form.html', context)
```

**template html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block conteudo%}
  <div class="container-fluid" id="formulario">
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="row">
              {{ form.id|as_crispy_field }}
              {{ form.nome|as_crispy_field }}
              {{ form.slug|as_crispy_field }}
              {{ form.descricao|as_crispy_field }}
              {{ form.projetista|as_crispy_field }}
              {{ form.setor|as_crispy_field }}
              {{ form.data|as_crispy_field }}
              {{ form.projeto|as_crispy_field }}
              {{ form.desenho|as_crispy_field }}
              {{ form.estruturaprojeto|as_crispy_field }}
              {{ form.estruturafixadores|as_crispy_field }}
              {{ form.arquivo3D|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-fluid py-4 w-100">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**saida do terminal**

```
ipdb> form.is_valid()
False
ipdb> form
<CadastroProjetoForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(id;nome;descricao;setor;data;projetista;slug;projeto;desenho;estruturaprojeto;estruturafixadores;arquivo3D)>
ipdb> form.cleaned_data['projeto']
*** KeyError: 'projeto'

form.cleaned_data['slug']
'damper-laminas-opostas-400x400mm'

ipdb> form.errors
{'projeto': ['Este campo é obrigatório.'], 'estruturaprojeto': ['Este campo é obrigatório.']}

ipdb> request.FILES
<MultiValueDict: {'projeto': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: DLO_-_600x350.dxf (application/octet-stream)>], 'estruturaprojeto': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: PDT-AGAIN (1).csv (application/vnd.ms-excel)>]}>
```

acabei de verificar que quando eu seleciono o arquivo a chave referente a esse arquivo some:

```
    ipdb> form
<CadastroProjetoForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(id;nome;descricao;setor;data;projetista;arquivoprojeto;desenho;estruturaprojeto;estruturafixadores;arquivo3D)>
ipdb> form.data
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['fakdfaojsfnasfjdnakfa'], 'id': ['2d8ddd98-3ccc-4117-827f-39f0526d6e92'], 'nome': ['Damper Lâminas Opostas 700x700mm'], 'descricao': ['Damper planificado para corte'], 'projetista': ['admin'], 'setor': ['DAC'], 'data': ['14/12/2021'], 'desenho': [''], 'estruturafixadores': [''], 'arquivo3D': ['']}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso Aconteça com alguém, aparentemente um erro bobo, quando for fazer estanciar o formulário que contem upload, tem que se passar `request.FILES` como paramento para que o formulário entenda que há arquivos a ser guardados. oq é bem lógico.

a estancia ficaria assim no `views.py`
`form = seuformulario(request.POST, request.FILES)`